# Positioning divs on each other

Tags: html, css

I have so much trouble figuring out where my mistake are. I want to build website with some divs on the right to each other...later there should be a horizontal navigation which automatically scroll to the right via anchors.
Anyways...each div has an image in the background and a container with some text. The navigation menu is fixed and is always displayed.

My trouble: Why is the text container not showing up on the first div?
Please see my fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/

Thank you in advance for reading and if so...for answering

Comment: It is in Chrome (17.0.963.56). What browser are you using?

Comment: @Grim... thanks for asking..firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like that a solution

http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/7/
I've put a position absolute on you slider

and i've put your container div out of the slider

**EDIT :**

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/13/ 
everything is relative
And i've given a height to your slider, and position your container to a negative top

Comment: thanks you very much...but look whats happening if there are mutiple images...they are put onto each other...not relative to the parent div...http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/11/

Comment: that somehow worked...i need to implement it into my context though...good idea with the negative top!

Answer (score 1):

If I did got you right, if you use `img` to set a background (which I think is not good at all), you should exclude it from the common layer (for example `position:absolute`), so the content could overlay it. Your problem is not in text, but in image.

Comment: position absolute is not working. Later it should be a slideshow in the backgreound...thats why i use the img tag. Position absolute is not working because i need the imag mutiple times relative to the parent div.(mutiple sceens). Thank you for answering though? Or is it better to manipulate the backround with javascript to get a slideshow?

Comment: Same thing: put your image in another container with `overflow:hidden` or something like that so you can manipulate slideshow, but the container itself should still be `position:absolute`. Try to imagine the hierarchy you want and then you will understand all layers you need.

Answer (score 1):

try to have each container a unique class and replace  with  for example and put the image to div background like

```
background:url('http://www.wiesenhof-online.de/upload/Chicken-Ribs-BBQ-quer.jpg');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/10/

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer to your question about the REASON behind this happening is that Z-INDEX only works with positioned elements and as you are not positioning your image element that's why 'some text' is buried behind the image and its z-index doesn't take effect.

Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/pvvFR/14/